Non-existence of complex valued function in unit disk with $f(z)|_{\partial\mathbb{D}}=\bar{z}$.
Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C} :|z|<1\}$
and $f(z)$ be continuous function on a disc $\bar{\mathbb{D} } $  such that $f(z)$ is holomorphic function in open unit disc which is continuous on $\mathbb{D}$ and $f(z)=\bar{z}$ at the boundary of unit disc.
We have to proove no such $f(z)$ exist.
It is clear that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ on the boundary of disc.
since $f(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ it has a tayler series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$  and as  $\lim_{|z|\to 1} f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$  a power series will converge to $\frac{1}{z}$ on unit circle which is a contradiction it violets continuity.
please correct me

"[...] a power series will converge to $\frac{1}{z}$ on unit circle which is a contradiction it [violates] continuity." I don't immediately see the reasoning. Why does it violate continuity?

we have a power series around $0$ , and you cant express $\frac{1}{z}$ as a taylor series around $0$

Have you met the results required to say $f(z) = 1/z$ for all $z \in \bar{\mathbb{D}}$ at this point? By the look of this question, I thought you haven't; but if you have, sure, and even then you need to show your work proving $f(z) = 1/z$ on $D$. My original point was, without those results, you only know $f(z)$ on the unit circle, and on the open unit disc $f(z)$ might not be $1/z$.

You certainly need a more precise argument.

@X-Rui yeah it might not be , thats why i used continuity

I'm confused. If you don't know $f(z)$ is $1/z$ on $D$, or near $0$ in particular, what continuity is violated? What is the implication you drew from continuity?

i thought, it is continuous then how can a taylor series around $0$ will converge to $1/z$,

Nothing you've said is wrong, but it's missing important steps. "How can a taylor series around $0$ converge to $1/z$" on the unit circle (!) is basically what you are asked to prove. Let me ask you this: how did you convince yourself that it's impossible? In more detail, please.

i tried to write $1/z$  as a power series around 0 which is impossible

How do you know that's not because you haven't tried hard enough?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here's another answer: if $f(z)$ is analytic on $\bar{\Bbb D}$ then $\int_{\partial\Bbb D} f(z)\,dz = 0$ by Cauchy's integral theorem; but if $f(z)=1/z$ on $\partial\Bbb D$ then $\int_{\partial\Bbb D} f(z)\,dz=2\pi i$ by the residue theorem.
(The argument still works if $f(z)$ is only analytic on $\Bbb D$ and continuous on $\partial\Bbb D$, but then one has to use some limiting argument that obscures the main point.)

amazing answer , we will  sequence of $0s$ coverging to $2\pi\iota$.

$f(z)$ is analytic on $\bar{\Bbb D}$ usually means that $f$ is analyitc in an open set containing $\Bbb D$ which is not given. Also, Cauchy's Theorem does not directly apply to the given case, though a limiting argument will work.

Which is why I phrased the answer the way I did.

Let $g(z)=zf(z)-1$. Then, $g$ is continuous on $\overline D$ and analytic in $D$. Also, $g(z)=0$ on the boundary. By Maximum Modulus Theorem we get $g(z)=0$ for all $z$. This contradicts the fact that $g(0)=-1$.
